# How much faster is SOR method?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the linear system of equations $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -a\\
-a & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$.

> How much faster is the [SOR method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation) for the optimal $\omega_{opt}$ and $a=0.8$?

I determined $\rho(J)=0.8$ and $\rho(G)=(0.8)^2=0.64$. It is $\rho(S) = \frac{1}{4}$ where $S$ is the iteration matrix of the SOR method. I know SOR is faster since the spectral radius is smaller but I don't know $\textbf{how}$ much faster. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation#Convergence_Rate) help?

Comment: The convergence rate has been expressed as the spectral radius $\rho(S)$, which is $\frac{1}{4}$ here and I know that the spectral radius determines the convergence behaviour but $\textbf{how much}$ faster is the SOR method compared to Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel here? How do i compare all these spectral radii?

Comment: You need 3 G steps and thus 6 J steps to get about the same error reduction as one S step. Apply logarithms if you need it more exact.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you! what's the exact logarithms formula? I used $-\frac{ln(10)}{ln(\rho)}$ to get the number of iterations for an error reduction of $10^{-1}$ and got 2 iterations for SOR, 5 for G and 10 for J

Comment: This is a heavily rounded version. The ratio of G steps for one S step is $\frac{\log(4)}{-\log(0.64)}=\frac{\log(2)}{\log(1.25)}=3.10628..$. The next close integer ratios of J:G:S after 6:3:1 are 56:28:9.